# Correlation between categorial variables (using group means)

Tags: r, variables, correlation, cross-correlation

I've got a data set where I asked participants to state their WTP for a product. Furthermore I have the following variables:

1. Location (Japan, USA, Germany)
2. Gender
3. Age (as factors like 18-24, ...)

I would like to create a correlation matrix but face the problem, that these are categorial variables. Can I do this with group means?
So far I tried to do a log linear analysis but the frequency is in fact not meaningful as older people represent only a small fraction of the total sample.

```
Total4ContingencyTable2<-xtabs(~ Location + Age + Gender, data = Total4)
saturatedmodel2 <-loglm(~ App*Age*Gender*Location, 
data=Total4ContingencyTable)
interactionmodel2 <- loglm(~ Location + Age + Gender + Location:Age +       
Location:Gender + Age:Gender, data = Total4ContingencyTable2)
mosaicplot(Total4ContingencyTable2, shade = TRUE, main = "Categorial 
Variables")
```

Comment: could you paste a fraction of the dataset that you used for the analysis?

Comment: sure. the dataset is available under: http://filehorst.de/d/ccpHrxlr

thought about a multivariate variance analysis. but not quite sure